# Terraform combine variables using locals

Tags: terraform

I want to combine 2 variables. I tried to use locales but I couldn't get the final result also even with flatten

Any other recommendation?
I tried to use this structure since the vpc module receives that object with a list of subnets, the idea is that in networks we can add the name of the subnet in the list

```
variable "subnets" {
  default = {
    "subnet-01" = {
      name          = "subnet-01"
      subnet_ip     = "10.10.10.0/24"
      subnet_region = "us-central1"
      description   = "This subnet has a description"
    }
    "subnet-02" = {
      name          = "subnet-02"
      subnet_ip     = "10.10.20.0/24"
      subnet_region = "us-central1"
      description   = "This subnet has a description"
    }
    "subnet-03" = {
      name          = "subnet-03"
      subnet_ip     = "10.10.20.0/24"
      subnet_region = "us-central1"
      description   = "This subnet has a description"
    }
  }
}
variable "networks" {
  default = {
    "test-network" = {
      subnets         = ["subnet-01", "subnet-02"]
        auto_create_subnetworks         = "false"
        mtu                             = "0"
    }
    "test-network-2" = {
      subnets         = ["subnet-03"]
      auto_create_net = false
        auto_create_subnetworks         = "false"
        mtu                             = "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to choose the following result?

```
networks = {
  test-network = {
    auto_create_subnetworks = false
    mtu                     = 0
    subnets = [
        subnet-01           = {
            name            = "subnet-01"
            subnet_ip       = "10.10.10.0/24"
            subnet_region   = "us-central1"
            description     = "This subnet has a description"
        }
        subnet-02           = {
            name            = "subnet-02"
            subnet_ip       = "10.10.20.0/24"
            subnet_region   = "us-central1"
            description     = "This subnet has a description"
        }
    ]
  }
  test-network-2 = {
    auto_create_subnetworks = false
    mtu                     = 0
    subnets = [
        subnet-03           = {
            name            = "subnet-03"
            subnet_ip       = "10.10.30.0/24"
            subnet_region   = "us-central1"
            description     = "This subnet has a description"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that result having an embedded loop:

```
locals {
  networks = {
    for name, network in var.networks : name => {
      "subnets" : [for subnet_name in network.subnets : var.subnets[subnet_name]],
      "auto_create_subnetworks" : network.auto_create_subnetworks,
      "mtu" : network.mtu
    }
  }
}
```

Also, please note, your `subnet-02` has the `name` of `subnet-01`, which might not be what you would want.

Comment: Thank you very much, the name of the subnets was an editing error.